# How can I differentiate between the meaning in the following words

Tags: meaning, morphology

How can I difference between the meaning in the following words?
- Audience it's noun
- Audible it's adjective
- Audition it's also noun
- Auditory it's also adjective

So, my question is we have two adjectives and nouns of the same free word. What is the difference between them in the meaning and how can I use them?
Thanks for your responding

Comment: Although they have the same root, they are four different words.  It would be useful to understand how the four different endings produce these four different meanings, but you can *get* the different meanings just from a dictionary.

Comment: It helps us to give you a better answer if we understand what research you might have already done to find the answer. There is some good advice in the help center on the [How do I ask a good question?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: In American football, an "audible" is also a noun.  It is usually a play called (out loud) by the quarterback at the line of scrimmage.

Comment: I cannot say it is a rule but I can say that if there is a noun then one of them refers to people, the other one refers to things or situation.

Comment: @Murat -- "Audience" has two common meanings.  The most common refers to the people watching and/or listening to a performance.  The other refers to a situation in which a monarch (or other noble) listens to a petition.

Comment: @Jasper well actually I refered to or compared 'audition' and 'audience' in the first sense you mentioned,which the people watching and/or listening to a performance.:)

Comment: @Murat I think "audience" is a good illustration of why we have "answerable with a dictionary" as a close reason. Many English words have different meanings even if they are being used as the same part of speech. A decent dictionary should list them all, where often a person might forget or not know some sense of the word, so their answer isn't as complete.

Comment: I don't think "go look them up in a dictionary" answers the question. I believe the OP is asking (not with perfect clarity, but hey, this site is for people who are learning English) how you could possibly _predict_ the meaning of each word. Or what explains the fact that you have four forms instead of just two? Clearly just converting a noun to an adjective doesn't dictate the meaning, so what does? To a native speaker, this is easy; to an EFL learner with a dictionary, it is not.

Comment: @BenKovitz I agree, which is why I didn't initiate a close vote, but the classification of, for example, "audible" as only an adjective confuses the issue where some research into the dictionary definitions might make the question more focused.

Comment: @ColleenV Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

All of these come from the same root Latin word "audīre", meaning *to hear*, but they have different meanings.

Audition - an event where one shows off a skill or technique in order to get a job or win a prize.  (It may have at one time been exclusively used to refer to an event where one shows off singing - but you can use it to refer to non-singing events).

Audible - able to be heard.

Audience - group of people attending an event, typically to watch it and not directly participate in it.  It can also less commonly mean an event where a royal figure is taking time to meet with someone ("audience with the king", etc.).

Auditory - having to do with the sense of hearing.

Answer (score 1):

Look them up in a dictionary. You can guess what a word might mean if you recognize its root and part of speech, but that would just be a guess.

It would be nice if there were some simple rules that you could say, "any word ending with -or means the person doing the thing", like "auditor" = "a person who audits", "creator" = "a person who creates", etc. But English isn't that simple, and I'd guess most other languages aren't either. A "janitor" is not a person who "janits", nor is a "boar" a person who "boes". Etc.